# Total number of ways 10 books can be arranged if 4 specific books may not be together?

Tags: self-study, combinatorics

I am trying to solve this albeit probably juvenile combination/permutation type question.

A person has 10 books, of which four are fiction books. How many ways can the 10 books be arranged so that all four fiction books are not together?

My reasoning thus far is this:

```
(Total number of ways without the restriction) minus (Total with books together)
i.e. 10! - (6! x 4!)
```

Am I on the right track? Thanks!

Comment: Add the self-study tag.

Comment: "4 of these books may not be next to each other on the shelf." - can you clarify whether this means the four books may not appear as a consecutive block of four, or whether it means none of the four books is allowed to touch any of the others?

Comment: Hi @Silverfish the question verbatim states "A person has 10 books, of which four are fiction books. How many ways can
the 10 books be arranged so that all four fiction books are **not** together?"

Comment: Could you edit that in to the question, rather than post it in the comments? That way it's easier for future readers to find

Comment: The question is vague on what constitutes an "arrangement."  It sounds like some kind of physical positioning, likely in a linear fashion.  But should the left-right sequence 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 be considered the same as the sequence 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1?  Could it be a circular arrangement? Does it matter whether the books are placed right side up or upside down? Perhaps if you could tell us the *statistical* context or motivation of this question its proper interpretation would become apparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, only that instead of 6! you should use 7!, because you have 7 entities - the other 6 books (non fiction) and the group of 4 fiction books that, although they should be together (in the complementary event), can still be moved as a group anywhere among the other 6 books. So in my opinion, if I understand the question correctly, the answer is
10! - (7! x 4!)

Comment: This formula, when applied to smaller and simpler situations, clearly gives wrong answers.  For instance, there are two ways to arrange two books of which one is fiction and the other non-fiction.  Your formula appears to give $2!-(2!\times 1!)=0$ as the answer.  That cannot be correct no matter how you interpret "arrangement"!

Comment: 0 is the correct answer to your simple example, because there is no way in which you can arrange the two books such that the fiction book(s) will not be together.

Comment: Umm... if there is only one fiction book, it's impossible for two of them to be together.  It sounds like that (at the very least) you should explain how you interpret the question.

Comment: The question says that not all (4) fiction books should be together. If you change the number 4 to 1, the requirement is that this one fiction book will not be together with itself, which is impossible, hence the answer 0 is the correct answer.

Comment: I don't know why I got a -1, especially since I have the right answer to the original question, i.e., 10! - 7!4!

Comment: It quite clearly is incorrect, as I have tried to explain, unless you have some obscure interpretation of the question that you haven't disclosed.  In my answer I have offered a second analysis and two examples in an effort to clarify what's going on.  I would guess that in the case of $n=5$ books, of which $k=3$ are non-fiction, you would propose the formula $5!-3!\times 3! = 84$, but that is much greater than the correct value of $12$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's suppose an "arrangement" is a determination of a linear order of the $n=10$ unique books, so that there are $n!$ possible arrangements.  In any such arrangement the $n-k=10-4=6$ non-fiction books will appear in some order and there are $$(n-k)!$$ ways to do that.  Independently of that arrangement of the non-fiction books, the fiction books have to be placed either before, between, or after the non-fiction books: there are $n-k+1 = 7$ such places.  *No such place may be occupied by more than one fiction book.*  There are $$\binom{n-k+1}{k}$$ choices of $k$ of those places in which to put the fiction books and $$k!$$ distinct arrangements of the fiction books for each such choice.

The answer therefore is

$$(n-k)!\binom{n-k+1}{k}k! = \frac{(n-k)!(n-k+1)!}{(n-2k+1)!}.\tag{1}$$

---

Another way to solve this is to note that when the books are arranged vertically on top of one extra non-fiction book, then every fiction book lies on top of a non-fiction book.  That will appear as $k=4$ pairs of fiction-nonfiction books interspersed between $n-2k+1=3$  nonfiction books, for which there are therefore $$\binom{n-2k+1+k}{k}=\binom{n-k+1}{k}$$ possibilities.  That implies the chance of seeing such a pattern within the set of all $n!$ possible arrangements is the ratio $$\frac{\binom{n-k+1}{k}}{\binom{n}{k}}.$$  Multiply this by $n!$ to get the answer $$\frac{\binom{n-k+1}{k}}{\binom{n}{k}}n!\tag{2}.$$

---

As an example, let $n=5$ books of which $k=2$ fiction books must be kept separated.  The formulae $(1)$ and $(2)$ give

$$\frac{(5-2)!(5-2+1)!}{(5 - 2(2) + 1)!} = \frac{3!4!}{2!}=72\tag{1a}$$

and

$$\frac{\binom{5-2+1}{2}}{\binom{5}{2}}5! = \frac{6}{10}120=72\tag{2a}.$$

In light of the second analysis, it suffices to illustrate this by showing all the valid *patterns* of the five books, writing "N" for non-fiction and "F" for fiction:

$$NNNFF, \color{red}{NNFNF}, \color{red}{NFNNF}, \color{red}{FNNNF}, NNFFN, \\\color{red}{NFNFN}, \color{red}{FNNFN}, NFFNN, \color{red}{FNFNN}, FFNNN$$

The red ones are the $\binom{4}{2}=6$ valid patterns out of all $\binom{5}{2}=10$ possible patterns.

As another example, let there be $k=3$ fiction books out of these five.  Now only one of the ten patterns is valid -- $FNFNF$ -- and indeed $1/10=\binom{3}{3}/\binom{5}{3}$.  Consequently there are only $120/10=12$ such arrangements.  They are found by applying any of the $3!=6$ permutations of the fiction books and $2!=2$ permutations of the non-fiction books within this arrangement.